# Different section contain different number of rows inside a Table View in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Suppose I have section 1, 2 and 3 in a Table View,

For section 1, it have 3 row
For section 2, it have 5 row
For section 3, it have  1 row

In Objective-c, how can I implement this action in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? Any additional things I need to do besides these two function? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If this is static data then do like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 3;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if(section==0)
return 3;
else if(section==1)
return 5;

return 1;
}
```

and if it is based on data base then make proper data structure and use it for managing.

Comment: If the data is dynamic, how can I achieve the same goal(different section with different no. of row)? Thanks

Comment: make dictionary for which you want to show and set an array in it with a key  and then fill in array then for number of section count of the array which contains dictionaries and for rows access a dictionary with indexPath.section and key (this gives an array),then count of this shows number of rows for that column.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0)
        return 3;

    if (section == 1)
        return 5;

    if (section == 2)
        return 1;

    return 0;

}
```

You also need to implement at lest the UITableViewDataSource method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: If the data is dynamic, how can I achieve the same goal(different section with different no. of row)? Thanks

Comment: you could, for example have an NSArray (or NSDictionary) of NSArrays, for example, return the count of the main array for number of sections, and the count of the sub-arrays for the number of rows in each section.

Comment: Might wanna use a switch statement for this case. Easier and more efficient to use.